# Atualizar Data Binding no NavBar após efetuar login

Tags: angularjs

Tenho um `navbar` que é incluído na pagina index.html

```
<body>
       <div class="container">
         <div ng-controller="colaboradorController" ng-include="'public/views/navBar.html'"></div>
         <div ng-view></div>
      </div>

      </div>
</body>
```

Até ai tudo bem, nesse navBar eu tenho um `Data Binding` aonde pego o usuário logado:

```
<p class="navbar-text usuarioLogado">{{usuarioLogado}}</p>
```

O controller que está sendo usado é o colaboradorController, nesse controller tenho uma função que pega o usuário logado:

```
var init = function () {
        var temp = sessionStorage.getItem('userLogado');
        var viewName = $.parseJSON(temp); 

        if(viewName != null){
            $scope.usuarioLogado = viewName.usuario.nome;
        }else{
            $scope.usuarioLogado = "";
        }
    };
```

E inicio essa função quando a página é aberta:

```
init();
```

O problema é que quando a página é aberta o `usuarioLogado` não é exibido no `NavBar`, ele só aparece após um `F5`. Já fiz um `console.log` pra ver se o está sendo carregando junto com a página e ele é carregado. Só não estou conseguindo atualizar de imediato esse `Navbar` que está sendo incluído em meu `index.html`.

Como resolvo esse problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pegar a informação do sessionStorage pode ser uma boa, mas nesse caso como o estado da variável é mutável seria bom se você colocasse um watch para observar a cada evento se o valor continua o mesmo.

Da uma olhada nesse link: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/angularjs-using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply), explica rapidamente como funciona o watch e o digest cycle.

O sessionStorage é bom pra economizar consultas de serviços, mas de coisas que tem um retorno definido, que não sofre alteração. Talvez isso ajude um pouco a esclarecer mais.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26172976/difference-between-session-storage-local-storage-and-cookies-in-angularjs)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Então o que está no sessionStorage é o usuário logado, acho que isso não irá sofrer atualização. Quando eu coloco o navBar direto na pagina, ou seja, sem inclui-lo no index.html funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Só queria uma solução para que eu não precise ficar colocando um navBar em cada página

Comment: E continua não precisando, como SPA o navbar pode ficar no index.html, sem necessidade de ser repetido em toda página. Se você não adicionar as variáveis contidas nele dentro de um clico de watches toda vez que vc mudar de página o bind do angular não irá atualizar as mudanças, essa mudanças só irão aparecer depois que vc der um refresh na página ou atualizar o serviço que pega as informações. Não é recomendado adicionar muitos watches na ferramenta, falam de um limite de até 2000(incluindo os watches já existentes no angularjs), logo tome cuidado ou sua aplicação pode ficar mto lenta